# Using dynamic in C# to access field of anonymous type - possible?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, dynamic-keyword

I've got a controller method:

```
public JsonResult CalculateStuff(int coolArg)
{
    if(calculatePossible)
       return Json(CoolMethod(coolArg));
    else return Json(new { Calculated = false });
}
```

Now, I'd like to test this.

```
public void MyTest
{
    var controller = GetControllerInstance();
    var result = controller.CalculateStuff().Data as dynamic;
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Calculated == false);        
}
```

This throws a RuntimeBinderException saying that Calculated is not defined. Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Following Jons' advice, I used InternalsVisibleTo to befriend my test assembly. Everything works fine. Thank you Jon.

Comment: @Patrick Well I would have done it immediately, but SO told me that I needed to wait 10 minutes... Will do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, but only within the same assembly. The anonymous type is internal.

It should also be okay if you use `InternalsVisibleTo` in your production assembly to grant access to your test assembly though.

Comment: Blerg. Thanks! :) (The blerg is because I would rather not use InternalsVisibleTo - but I guess it's fine since the assembly after all is logically quite tightly paired to the test assembly.)